# Failed to start the Construct Kafka Consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, kerberos, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I am trying to develop a Consumer class in Spring Boot for the Kafka (kerberos). I made necessary changes according to kerberos settings as suggested by Gary ([Invalid Keystore Format, BootStrap Broker Disconnected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56531996/invalid-keystore-format-bootstrap-broker-disconnected)) and ended up with the below error. I could able to setup the Kafka Cluster Setup with same keytab/jks files locally.

```
Failed to start bean 'org.springframework.kafka.config.internalKafkaListenerEndpointRegistry'; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer

Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer

Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unable to obtain password from user
```

Answer (score 0):

most of the times the above error is due to either Keytab is corrupt or permissions on your key tab is not correct.

1. make sure you have `chmod 400` permission on your key tab
2. do a `kinit` and check if your key tab is valid.

please post your code if you need more help.

Comment: Thank you. This is resolved once I copied the US_Policy.jar and some other to my jdk security libs